# This is a diode related problem: Assuming the diodes used in the circuit are ideal. Find the current through the resistor

Tags: diodes

I tried to solve this question but i donot know how to solve. Any one can help?
Assuming the diodes used in the circuit are ideal. Find the current through the resistor.
[image]

I asked in foroum and got the answers:
Here total voltage=6V[since voltage is added in parallel]

change in voltage(V)=6-0=6V

[since earth has 0 voltage]

Resistance(R) =1000 ohms

now, R=V/I

1000=6/I

I=6/1000

Therefore current(I) is 6mA

I dont think this is right.
Is'nt voltage added in series?

Comment: Draw the complete circuit with three voltage sources connected to the ground point where the resistor is connected.  Then think carefully about the flow of current.

Comment: @CharlesCowie  what if voltage source are in series?.  Can you provide complete explanation for this question. It will be helpful

Comment: What makes you think the voltage sources could be in series?

Comment: @CharlesCowie Cant the voltage source be connected in series? can you explain about this question clearly?

Comment: How would you draw the circuit if the voltage sources are connected in series?

Comment: I would suggest you go back to definitions. What are the properties of an ideal voltage source? What are the properties of an ideal diode? Once you know those, and have redrawn the circuit as Charles Cowie suggests, the answer will probably be apparent.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a study or homework problem without sufficient effort to solve demonstrated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is'nt voltage added in series?

No. All the voltages in this circuit are relative to the common ground.

> Here total voltage=6V[since voltage is added in parallel]

No. Voltage sources add when connected in [series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits). For this to work the voltage sources must be 'isolated' from each other, ie. have no common connection. Different voltages in parallel are impossible, because you can only have one voltage between two connection points (nodes).

An 'ideal' diode drops 'infinitesimal' voltage when conducting. Therefore when D3 is conducting the voltage across the resistor is (infinitesimally smaller than) 3 V.

But what about the other diodes? D1 will only conduct if the voltage at its cathode (relative to ground) is less than 1 V, and D2 will only conduct if its cathode is less than 2 V. With a voltage of 3 V on their cathodes, both D1 and D2 will be reverse biased and pass no current. The diodes prevent the 1 V and 2 V supplies from 'shorting out' the 3 V supply, allowing the voltage across the resistor to become 3 V.